# escaping question mark in regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, literals

This is a simple question I think.

I am trying to search for the occurrence of a string in another string using regex in JavaScript like so:

```
 var content ="Hi, I like your Apartment. Could we schedule a viewing? My phone number is: ";

 var gent = new RegExp("I like your Apartment. Could we schedule a viewing? My", "g");

 if(content.search(gent) != -1){   
     alert('worked');     
 }
```

This doesn't work because of the `?` character....I tried escaping it with `\`, but that doesn't work either. Is there another way to use `?` literally instead of as a special character?

Comment: The worst part about this is that even using a string instead of a regex causes this problem, eg `str.search("?")` That definitely seems like a bug because that's not a regex and shouldn't be getting treated as a one. 

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You need to escape it with two backslashes

```
\\?
```

See this for more details:

http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/Regular%20Expressions%20Simple%20Usage.htm

Comment: … one for the regex and one for the string declration.

Comment: Mind blow! After years of working with regex, thought I saw everything.. But no, here you go. Double escape. Guess one day I'll see triple.

Answer (score 32):

You should use double slash:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\?", "g");
```

Why? because in JavaScript the `\` is also used to escape characters in strings,  so: "\?" becomes: `"?"`

And `"\\?"`, becomes  `"\?"`

Answer (score 17):

You can delimit your regexp with slashes instead of quotes and then a single backslash to escape the question mark. Try this:

```
var gent = /I like your Apartment. Could we schedule a viewing\?/g;
```

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you have a *known* pattern (i.e. you do not use a variable to build a RegExp), use *literal* regex notation where you only need to use *single* backslashes to escape special regex metacharacters:

```
var re = /I like your Apartment\. Could we schedule a viewing\?/g;
                               ^^                            ^^
```

Whenever you need to build a RegExp dynamically, use *`RegExp` constructor notation* where you MUST *double backslashes for them to denote a literal backslash*:

```
var questionmark_block = "\\?"; // A literal ?
var initial_subpattern = "I like your Apartment\\. Could we schedule a viewing"; // Note the dot must also be escaped to match a literal dot
var re = new RegExp(initial_subpattern + questionmark_block, "g");
```

And if you use the `String.raw` string literal you may use `\` as is (see an example of using a template string literal where you may put variables into the regex pattern):

```js
const questionmark_block = String.raw`\?`; // A literal ?
const initial_subpattern = "I like your Apartment\\. Could we schedule a viewing";
const re = new RegExp(`${initial_subpattern}${questionmark_block}`, 'g'); // Building pattern from two variables
console.log(re); // => /I like your Apartment\. Could we schedule a viewing\?/g
```

A must-read: [*RegExp: Description*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) at MDN.