# How to replace "?" or "&" from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How to replace *"?test=666&test"* to *"222"* in the following code?

If my code has "?" or "&", it will not work.

```html
<body>
  hello
  <br>
  ?test=666&test

  <script>
    function rp (str, map) {
      for (var i in map) {
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(i, 'g'), map[i]);
      }
      return str;
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = rp(document.body.innerHTML, {
        'hello': '111',
        '?test=666&test': '222'
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You escape them (and any other characters that have special meaning in the regex), more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Comment: ? is wild char for Regex, You need to escape them if you want to use themselves in a string. Ex: ?test=666&test has to given like this, \?test=666\&test. As @PeterB said not sure about & char

Comment: You need to use `\\?` in the string. This way the string will contain `\?`. Only this will work in the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [escaping question mark in regex javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889957/escaping-question-mark-in-regex-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`?` and `&` and several other characters have special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape them (with a `\`) to use them literally.

[This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) describe doing so in the general case.

Using a hypothetical `escapeRegex` function derived from those answers, you'd do:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegex(i), 'g'), map[i]);
```

To *just* handle `?` and `&`, you'd do this (but **don't do this**, it leaves the door open for other special chars):

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp(i.replace(/[?&]/g, "\\$&")., 'g'), map[i]);
```

Comment: `str = str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegex(i), 'g'), map[i]); `

this is not work . could you help me again?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of escaping and encoding in various different ways:

1. In **regex**, `?` is a modifier. You need to escape it and use `\?` instead.
2. In a **javascript string literal**, `\` is a special character. To get a *single backslash* in a string you need to write `'\\'`, and to get `\?` in a string you need to write `'\\?'`
3. In **HTML**, a simple `&` translates to `&amp;`. To match that encoded character, you need to look for `&amp;`

This is the result of what you should use:

```js
function rp(str, map) {
  for (var i in map) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(i, 'g'), map[i]);
  }
  return str;
}
document.body.innerHTML = rp(document.body.innerHTML, {
  'hello': '111',
  '\\?test=666&amp;test': '222'
});
```

```html
<body>
  hello
  <br>
  ?test=666&test
</body>
```

Comment: thanks. it's cool.  and i want another way. i want to change my code , not change the `?test=666&test`. thanks a lot.