# regex matching QUESTION MARK in url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want javascript regex for a question mark in url to work
I have 3 urls

the requirement is to create a regex for first 2 urls and not the third one.

```
1st url -- https://www.abc.xyz/search/?collection=check&query=activity
2nd url-- https://www.abc.xyz/search?collection=check&query=activity
3rd url -- https://abc.xyz/searchapps/?query=activity
```

`(/\/search\//.test(window.location.pathname))` works for 1st but not for 2nd

if I use `(/\/search?/.test(window.location.pathname)` it works for 2nd url However the problem is it also matches 3rd url https://abc.xyz/searchapps/?query=activity

Comment: `/\/search?/` matches `/search` and `/searc` - it doesn't match the question mark, since it's a special character.

Comment: thanks @vlaz but how to make it work for first 2 url and not third one

Comment: Escape the question mark. Same as how you did with with the forward slash.

Comment: Escape it - `/\/search\?/`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890001/3832970)

Comment: i tried /\/search\?/ it doesnt work

Comment: /\/search\?/ will look for specifically "/search?", is that not what you want? Edit: I see the difference between the first two lines, will update

Comment: i did it in the console but it doesnt print test


 if(/\/search\?/.test(window.location.pathname))console.log('test');

Comment: `/\/search\/?\?/` - optional backslash at the end and a mandatory question mark. Although it seems easier to parse the URL instead of do regex matches.

Comment: `/\/search(\/?)\?/` addresses /search/? and /search?, like the first two examples you gave. If that doesn't work there may be another issue

Comment: tried it in the console and it doesnt work so pls suggest
if(/\/search(\/?)\?/.test(window.location.pathname))console.log('test');

hit the url and put this in console you won't see 'test' getting printed

Comment: `window.location.pathname` will NOT give you the query string, it will just return `/search`. You can see that if you do `console.log(window.location.pathname)`. And you can see the regex working if you try `console.log(/\/search(\/?)\?/.test("https://www.abc.xyz/search/?collection=check&query=activity"))`

Comment: thank you @vlaz i made it to window.location.href and it worked if(/\/search(\/?)\?/.test(window.location.href))console.log('test');