# Javascript: Highlighting part of a string with <b> tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to highlight a match in a string by inserting `<b>` tags around the matching substring.  For example, if the query is "cat" then:

```
"I have a cat."
```

should become:

```
"I have a <b>cat</b>."
```

Likewise, if the query is "stack overflow", then:

```
"Stack Overflow is great."
```

should become:

```
"<b>Stack Overflow</b> is great."
```

In other words, I have to preserve the case of the original string, but not be case-sensitive when matching.

One thing I was trying so far is:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'i');
return strResult.replace(regex, '<b>$1</b>');
```

However, this causes a runtime exception if query has any parenthesis in it, and I think it'd be too much hassle to attempt to escape all the possible regular expression characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of, or related to, [Case insensitive string replacement in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280793/case-insensitive-string-replacement-in-javascript)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "[Escape Regular Expression Characters in String - JavaScript](http://snipplr.com/view/9649/escape-regular-expression-characters-in-string/)" for information about how to escape special regex characters, such as `()`

EDIT: Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280793/case-insensitive-string-replacement-in-javascript) older SO question that asks a **very** similar - almost identical - question.

Comment: Thanks, that first link was exactly what I needed..  I've added it to my growing library of utility functions.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex to manipulate HTML.

For example if the query is ‘cat’, then:

```
I have a <em class="category">dog</em>
```

will become a mess of broken markup. In cases where the query and text may be user-generated, the resulting HTML-injection attacks are likely to leave you with cross-site-scripting security holes.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501007/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-style-parts-of-all-instances-of-a-specific-word) for an example of how to find and mark up text using a regex in the DOM.

(For completeness, here is a function to escape regex-special characters, since the version linked at snipplr is insufficient. It fails to escape `^` and `$`, plus `-` which is special in character groups.)

```
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
};
```

Comment: The input is a string, not HTML.  I'm only returning HTML.

Comment: Then what if the string contains HTML-special characters? Again, cross-site-scripting.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a highlight plugin?

- http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: That's a fine plugin and I've used it; it doesn't allow regexes but that may be OK for the original question.