# Counting dots with javascript returns half

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've written a small function to count the amount of occurrences of a character within a string. It's been working just fine.

Until i tried to count dots, it keeps giving me half the number it should. What am i doing wrong? Am i not escaping the dots in the right manner?

```
function count(s1, letter) {
    return (s1.length - s1.replace(new RegExp(letter, "g"), '').length) / letter.length;
}

var loc = 'http://www.domain.com/page' // I'm actually using window.location.href in practice.

var someStringWithDots = 'Yes. I want. to. place a. lot of. dots.';

var somestring = 'abbbcdefg';

count(somestring, 'b');
//returns 3 - correct

count(someStringWithDots, '\\.');
//returns 3 - incorrect

count(loc, '\\.');
//returns 1 - incorrect
```

Comment: Have you tried not escaping periods at all and just doing
    count(loc, '.')
?

Comment: I have, and because a dot matches all characters in regExp it wil return the length of the entire string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use .match and you're done:

```
function count(s1, letter) {
    return ( s1.match( RegExp(letter,'g') ) || [] ).length;
}

count('Yes. I want. to. place a. lot of. dots.','\\.'); //=> 6
```

[**edit**] In case no match is found, `.length` would throw an error.
Added a workaround for that (`... || []`)

Answer (score 2):

That's because `letter.length` is 2 and you divide the result by that.

Try to remove the escape characters from the string `letter` before you count the size or, even better, escape the letter in `count()`.

Comment: However i see that this the explanation for the problem. I don't know how to dynamically escape the dot. escape() unescape() doesn't work for this it seems.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280793/case-insensitive-string-replacement-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You're dividing by `letter.length` but that does not use the completely un-escaped version of your string, therefore you're diving in fact by two.

```
'\\.' un-esacped is \.
`\\.`.length is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function count(s1, letter) {
var result = split(s1,letter);
if(result && result.length >0)
    return result.length - 1;
else
 return 0;
}
```