# What does \\$& in "str.replace(specials, "\\$&")" mean?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am refering to code from [Case insensitive string replacement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280793/case-insensitive-string-replacement-in-javascript/280970#280970):

```
RegExp.escape = function(str) 
{
  var specials = new RegExp("[.*+?|()\\[\\]{}\\\\]", "g"); // .*+?|()[]{}\
  return str.replace(specials, "\\$&");
}
```

What does `\\$&` mean?

I think `\\` escapes the `\` character. Then `$&`, I thought it should be `$1` to match the 1st match? tho `$1` does not work right

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$&` represents the entire (sub)string matched by the regex, regardless of capture groups. The replacement result you get is each match in your string being escaped by a literal backslash (represented by `\\`). Since the regex used here consists only of a character class, "each match" refers to each metacharacter listed in the character class that is matched.

For example, the regex string `[abc]` will be replaced with `\[abc\]`:

- `[` is matched as it occurs in the character class. Represented by `$&`, replaced with `\[`
- `a`, `b` and `c` are not metacharacters in the character class, so they're ignored
- `]` is matched as it occurs in the character class. Represented by `$&`, replaced with `\]`

Answer (score 1):

`$&` is the entire match, which in the example is whichever special character was matched. `$1` doesn't work since there is no group `(...)` in the regex (though if you added parentheses around the square brackets, then it would also work).

Yes, the first '\' escapes the other (usually a backslash is used in conjunction with the following character to give it special meaning, so to get a literal backslash it needs to be escaped using another backslash).

Answer (score 0):

That regex is not using a capture group. Apparently he is using a common regex variable:

`$& returns the entire matched string (some systems its $0)`
In this case he is just matching 1 character at a time
equivalent to `s/[.*+?|()\[\]{}\\]/\\$&/g`

Obscure fact: In Perl there is a function called quotemeta("your string") that does this
or it can be inlined in the regex with \Q. I love Perl.

As a side note, he might have left out the carret ^ and possibly, but not sure, the $
The fact that there is no built-in or inline method might be a bad thing. And escaping metachars like this must be thought out, as regex fragments can be problematic.