# How to Find and replace parts of string in case insensitive way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

I have such [simple example.](http://jsfiddle.net/uDdbq/15/) I want to replace text in for example `add ann.c` same way I replace it in `add Ann.c`. How to do it with jQuery?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uDdbq/19/) is how I've done it: `$("#tags").val().replace(dictionary[j]['name'].toLowerCase(), dictionary[j]['realvalue']);` Sorry for bothering... but any more optimal solutions are much welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280793/case-insensitive-string-replacement-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#tags").val().toLowerCase(); // will convert all uppercase characters to lowercase ones
```

Then it looks for e.g. `ann.c` so you'd need to alter the object:

```
var dictionary = jQuery.parseJSON('[ { "name": "ann.c",  "realvalue": "./34534j435345j3b3"  }, {   "name": "ann.h",   "realvalue": "./333dfsdGjh45j3b5" }]');
```

By the way what about:

```
var dictionary = [ { "name": "ann.c",  "realvalue": "./34534j435345j3b3" },
                   { "name": "ann.h",  "realvalue": "./333dfsdGjh45j3b5" } ];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/uDdbq/18/

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regexp object that has the `i` (case-insensitive) flag set.

You can safely build a regexp object from an arbitrary string provided that you [escape that string first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $("#tags").val().replace(RegExp(dictionary[j]['name'],"i"), dictionary[j]['realvalue']);
```

you can convert the string to a regex and add case insensitive to it.