# Javascript URL Regex That Checks Regex with URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this URL...

```
http://www.google.com/local/add/analytics?hl=en-US&gl=US
```

And I want to check these URLs to see if they matches above URL...

```
www.google.com/local/add*
www.google.com/local/add/*
http://www.google.com/local/add*
http://www.google.com/local/add/*
https://www.google.com/local/add*
https://www.google.com/local/add/*
```

You can see the input URL is also a regex having * so what regex that I can use to match a list of URLs with a regex to see if the url exists? Currently I am doing this...

```
var isAllowed = (url.indexOf(newURL) === 0);
```

Which is definitely not efficient.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. What is the purpose of the asterix (*)? does it mean a wildcard in the non-regex way?

Comment: @Variant I would assume the * is a wildcard yes.. and that the OP would like to validate the url against these 'cases'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not the cleanest regex i've ever written but I think it should work.

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/local/add/analytics?hl=en-US&gl=US";
var reg = /((https|http|)(\:\/\/|)www\.google.com\/local\/add(\/|)).*/;
console.log(reg.test(url));
```

this will return true for all of these cases

> www.google.com/local/add* 
>   www.google.com/local/add/* 
>   http://www.google.com/local/add* 
>   http://www.google.com/local/add/* 
>   https://www.google.com/local/add* 
>   https://www.google.com/local/add/*

it *should* look for (`http` or `https` or nothing) then (`://` or nothing) then `www.google.com/local/add` then (`/` or nothing) then anything.

the one case it will also return true that I will leave for you is the case `(http|https)www.google.com/local/add(/|)*`

Comment: I do implore you to test the crap out of this if you are going to use it.. possibly read up a bit more on regex and improve on it (i'm no regex master myself... in fact i barley scrape by :P)

Answer (score 1):

```
var reg = new RegExp("(https?://)?(www.)?google.com/local/add/?"),
    URL = "http://www.google.com/local/add/analytics?hl=en-US&gl=US";

console.log(reg.test(URL));
```

I've used the `?` a lot, which means, whatever character precedes the question mark may or may not be matched.

`https?` means the `s` may or may not be there. `(www.)?` means that the `www.` may be absent entirely. You hopefully get how it works now.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KkEG4/)

[Learn how to use Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: ahhh. see I did not know that about `?`. good show, good show.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you, you want something like this:

Convert the input URL to a regex. E.g.:

```
var input = "http://www.google.com/local/add*";
var reg_url = input .replace(/\*/g,".*").replace(/\./g,"\\.");
```

you might need to escape some more characters, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280805/518587)

And check if it matches:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/local/add/analytics?hl=en-US&gl=US";
var isAllowed = url.search(reg_url) >= 0;
```