# JS .replace place b tag in string where == string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case insensitive string replacement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280793/case-insensitive-string-replacement-in-javascript)

I am trying to highlight part of a string where it is equal to another variable value.

For example

```
var string = 'This Is A Test String';
var findWord = 'test';
```

result should be

```
'This Is A <b>Test</b> String'
```

Please note the case insensitive and that I require the use of using variables to pass the 'find/Replace word'

reason I need to do it this was is to keep the exact form/case of the string found where is == to the search word.

In PHP, this works, so basically I'm after the JS equivalent of

```
preg_replace('/('.$search.')/i','<b>$1</b>',$val['name'])
```

I'm not good when it comes to regex, this should be simple for someone.

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Comment: A note about the answers given: This won't work with special regexp characters apparent in the needle. Make sure to escape them, but don't escape everything since "escaping" can also make for a special token (`\d`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'This Is A Test String';
var w = 'test';

var result = str.replace(new RegExp(w, 'gi'), function(match) {
  return "<b>" + match + "</b>";
});
```

EDIT: Or, as suggested by the comment, the last line could be replaced by:

```
var result = str.replace(new RegExp(w, 'gi'), "<b>$&</b>");
```

Comment: This won't discard the capitalization of the original string.

Comment: You don't need a function here, just use `$&`

Comment: Excellent, this would brilliantly, is this the most time efficient way of achieving this as I have to do this on a large number of string extremely quickly?

Comment: @BenJohnson: I honestly don't know :) You'd probably have to write an alternative and profile the different solutions. I think it'll be hard to beat something as built-in as this though.

Comment: Thanks @Jakob! I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, hopefully one day i'll understand what is going on!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
var string = "This is a test string.",
needle = "test",
re = new RegExp(needle, "gi"),
newString = string.replace(re, "<strong>" + needle + "</strong>");
console.log(newString);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FVz2D/).

Note that I used `<strong></strong>` rather than `<b></b>` (deliberately), though, of course, you can use whatever element-type you like. Also, the `gi` flags:

- `g` is for a global search, rather than simply stopping at the first match, and
- `i` is for case-insensitive, so `'test'` will match `Test`,`tESt` and so on...

---

**Edited** to preserve capitalization of the matched string/substring:

```
var string = "This is a Test string.",
    needle = "test",
    re = new RegExp(needle, "gi"),
    newString = string.replace(re, function(a,b){
        return "<strong>" + a + "</strong>";
    });

document.getElementById('input').appendChild(document.createTextNode(string));
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = newString;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FVz2D/1/).

---

**Edited** to create a more functional/reusable approach:

```
function formatMatches(el, needle, wrapper) {
    if (!el || !needle) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var re = new RegExp(needle, "gi"),
            haystack = el.textContent,
            o = '<' + wrapper + '>',
            c = '</' + wrapper + '>';
        return haystack.replace(re, function(a) {
            return o + a + c;
        });
    }
}

var needle = "test",
    el = document.getElementById('input'),
    wrapper = 'strong';

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = formatMatches(el, needle, wrapper);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FVz2D/2/).

References:

- [`node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild).
- [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3adocument.createTextNode).
- [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: This will discard the capitalization of the original string.

Comment: Ah; I hadn't realised, somehow, that that was a requirement. Corrected.