# jquery .html() replace case sensitivity

Tags: jquery, html, string, replace

i am trying to build a string search by using Jquery. My page contains number of paragraph tags which contains text. My code is as below:

```
$("#search_button").click(function(event){
var keyword = $("#searchkeyword").val();
var paras = $("p:contains('" + keyword + "')").each(function(){
$(this).html(
$(this).html().replace( keyword ,'<span style=color:red>  "' + keyword + '" </span>')
);
});
$('#search_results').html(paras);
event.preventDefault();
});
```

The search works fine . I am having problem with html.replace() which is only replacing the exact case matching words. Suppose i search for word "apple", html.replace() will only replace the string if the text contains exactly the word "apple" but if i search for "Apple", the search still works but in that case html.replace() does not works since the string contains word "apple" not "Apple". how can i remove case sensitivity of html.repalce in my code?

Comment: If you want case-insensitive matching, you have to use a regular expression with the `i` modifier. String replacing is always case-sensitive.

Comment: Also note that jQuery's `:contains()` pseudo-selector is case-sensitive.

Comment: i have overridden the :contains selector by the following code: jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

Comment: OK, although it would probably be better to add a new pseudo-selector `:icontains` instead of overriding the normal one. Anyway, my first comment still applies, use a regular expression to do a case-insensitive string replacement.

Comment: @Barmar can you show me an example or modify my code for the regexp, since i am new to jquery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

thats easy with regular expressions, try change this line:

```
$(this).html().replace( keyword ,'<span style=color:red>  "' + keyword + '" </span>')
```

for this one:

```
$(this).html().replace( new RegExp(keyword, "ig") ,'<span style=color:red>  "' + keyword + '" </span>')
```

In the RegExp the "i" parameter will do the trick and the "g" will repeat the replace again if it finds more than one coincidence of keyword in the string produced by $(this).html()

Comment: Unfortunately, If the word was Capitalised and the search term was lowercase, the search term will replace the capitalised occurrence with the lower case search term.

Answer (score 5):

Old question but a better answer would be:

```
$(this).html().replace( new RegExp('('+keyword+')', 'ig') ,'<span style="color:red"> $1 </span>' )
```

The current top answer will change the capitalized letters to lower case. The extra parentheses in new Regexp() will store the value found. The $1 in .replace() inserts the stored value so character cases will be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#search_button").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var keyword = $("#searchkeyword").val().toLowerCase(),
        paras   = $('p').filter(function() {
                     return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) != -1;
        }).html(function(_, html) {
            var reg = new RegExp('(' + keyword + ')', 'gi');
            return html.replace(reg, "<span class='red'>$1</span>");
        });

    $('#search_results').html(paras);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EWBL3/2/)

Note that you're moving (not copying) the paragraphs into the `#search_result` element, and on the next search overwriting them, and they won't magically return, they gone !

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is a replace using case insensitive, like this:

```
msg = 'This is a Case Sensitive message';
msg.replace(/case/gi, "case");
"This is a case Sensitive message"
```

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression. I'm not good at constructing regExps, though. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280793/case-insensitive-string-replacement-in-javascript) out, it might help.

By the way, the method '[replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)' is native of javascript, not jquery

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem of case changing, so I found a workaround by doing the following.

```
const originalText = "Your HTML";
const replacementText = "html"

// To keep original case
const originalString = originalText.toLowerCase();
const subString = replacementText.toLowerCase();
const index = originalString.indexOf(subString);

replacementText = originalText.substring(index, index + replacementText.length);

originalText.replace(new RegExp(replacementText, "ig"), '<i>' + replacementText + '</i>');
```